# PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer for Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch project and I am bundling it as jar package.I have some properties files which I want to externalize outside my jar package.

For that , I am using Environment variable for resolving path given in propertyplaceholder's location property.And it's successfully getting resolved as I can see in logs that

**Loading properties from xyz location**

But when it comes to resolving placeholder which I specified in bean definition it can not resolve it and application fails there.

How come this is happening if the properties file is being loaded correctly.I have heard that if two PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer are present in our application this happens but I do not understand this.

Can anyone please give me some insight why this is happening?

Comment: can you post your context.xml(s)?

Comment: are you injecting @Value inside spring batch tasklet?

Comment: context.xml is almost similar to a standard declaration of a bean of PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer having some location values of properties file plus some other properties.I guess the problem is loading of more than one PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer through the application.

Comment: @Piyush. I am not injecting through annotation but I am passing the values for the datasource bean in config xml only like databse driver,username and all